# Different float variables in C giving different sizes

Tags: c, floating-point, size, byte

This might be a ver "noob-ish" question, but I've searched through the internet and couldn't find an answer. I know that in C, each type of variable is of a different size:

```
char   : 1 byte
short  : 2 bytes
int    : 4 bytes
long   : 4 bytes
float  : 4 bytes
double : 8 bytes
```

But let's say for example, I declare a variable `a` of tpye float and a variable `b` also of type float. Now let's say variable `a` gets assoicated a floating point number such as 130.25 and `b` gets associated 5.5. Now, taking into account that floats are 4 bytes long, surely `a` and `b` are not of the same size once I associate them their respective values. Is that correct? Or are the variables of the same size regardless of their values assoicated to them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A variable's size depends on its type, not on its value.

Two `float` variables will always be the same size, regardless of the value stored in them.

Notice that you can do e.g.:

```
float a;
float b;

if(sizeof a == sizeof b)
  printf("a and b have the same size\n");
```

The above is valid even if, as shown, the variables' values are *undefined*. This is because `sizeof` can be evaluated at compile-time, and thus not depend on the actual values at all. This is another proof that the value does not affect the size of the variable.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you perhaps explain to me why, when attempting to copy a floating point variable into a buffer of type `char` defined as `char[40]`, I can only store up until a certain value of the floating point? For example, I can store a float of value 1550.55 for example, but not a value of 2000.45.

Comment: @Adam I would love to try, please post a separate real question, including the code you've tried. A question like that is wrong for a comment, it should be a real question.